# Are try except clauses idiomatically discouraged in Python when avoidable?

Tags: python, idioms, try-except

Is a try except clause discouraged in Python if it can be avoided and is part of a normally functioning piece of code? For example, in the following two code snippets, which is preferred?

**Option 1:**

```
try:
    id = list.index(42)
except:
    print("42 not found")
else:
    print("ID: ", id)
```

**Option 2:**

```
if 42 in list:
    id = list.index(42)
    print("ID: ", id)
else:
    print("42 not found")
```

Comment: No, they are not. A recommended design principle in python is EAFP, instead of LBYL, see [Python Glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)

Comment: FYI: `EAFP:` Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission, and `LBYL:` Look Before You Leap

Comment: Well, actually there could be many more issues with a program other than simple checks. in fact try/catch are encouraged and are considered good practice.

Comment: And on the topic of good Python style - don't name variables after standard type names, as tempting as this might be. So no lists named "list", dicts named "dict", tuples named "tuple", or strings named "str".

Comment: @PaulMcGuire you shouldn't even name strings `list`, dicts `str`, or lists `dict` :P

Comment: Trying it is the best way to find out if something will work.  `list.index()` is more likely to know what is valid than you are.

Answer (score 2):

They are not discouraged.

However, your example is silly because you do not *need* an exception and you could for example accidentally have typos in your `list.index` code, which would trigger your exception, and you would never know.

Use exceptions and *catch* them if you know what exception you are catching -- and it's not trivial to do a "look before you leap" check (like it is in your example). Often that won't be the case. However, in your example it is.

Oh, and try to avoid a blanket `except:` catch (especially if you know *how* you expect your `try` to fail). That can easily enable bad practice since you pretty much by definition have no idea what your call might do/raise. If your application *requires* this (such as the server example pointed out by Paul in comments) that is fine, but if you are trying to lookup a value in a list? That's... not good.

As a good example of why this isn't good combined for your example:

```
try:
    id = list.idex(42)
except:
    print("42 not found")
else:
    print("ID: ", id)
```

Comment: I disagree. `except Exception:` is nothing to be avoided, and is often used in server apps to avoid crashing a long-running service because of badly behaved code. The case to avoid is the bare `except:`, and even worse `except: pass`, which *does* grab all exceptions, and then merrily trudges on. The killer is that `except:` also catches exceptions you normally want to let thru, like KeyboardInterrupt (when hitting ^C) or SysExit - `except: pass` in a while-True-loop will make for a difficult program to kill.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I clarified to address that - I mistakenly put `Exception:` instead of `except:` when I wrote this the first time...

Answer (score 0):

All depends on your needs:

If you have a significant dependence on the performance, `try`-`except` clauses are discouraged.

Otherwise you can use `try`-`except` clauses as a clear pattern.

Anyway, in your example I think the `if`-`else` code clearer than the `try`-`except` one.